# behave can't find step file

Tags: python-3.x, python-behave

I am getting output :

```
ABORTED: By user.
0 features passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
0 scenarios passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
0 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m0.000s
```

I am using python and behave, Following is my directory structure for feature file :

```
features
    -steps
       -Login
          -loginSteps.py 
          -__init__.py
    -featurefile.feature
```

In behave.ini , I have set : `paths=features/steps`

Answer (score 2):

Subdirectories cannot be placed in steps folder.

you can use:

```
features
    -steps
       -loginSteps.py 
    -featurefile.feature
```

or

```
features
    -steps
       -__init__.py
       -login
          -loginSteps.py
    -featurefile.feature
```

where

```
# features/steps/__init__.py
from features.steps.login import loginSteps
```